# How can I convert data pulled from API to CSV

Tags: json, api, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert the data from an api above to a csv but I am running into the issue below.

Sample Data from API:

**[["data_type_code","time_slot_id","seasonally_adj","category_code","cell_value","time"],
["MPCIM","757","no","44000","1.1","2013-01"],
["MPCSM","757","no","44000","-19.9","2013-01"]]**

Below is my code

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pprint
from config import api_key

query_url = "https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/eits/mrts?get=data_type_code,time_slot_id,seasonally_adj,category_code,cell_value&time=2010&key="+api_key

response = requests.get(query_url).json()
response.to_csv(r'/2010.csv')
```

Error image

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data from the API is in list. If you are doing any processing after getting a JSON response then maybe this could work for you assuming that the first list are the headings.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data[1:], columns = sample_data[0])
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

If you are getting a JSON response instead and not processing it into list.

```
df = pd.read_json(sample_data)
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish!

Comment: Glad i could help! :)